# how to refresh a string every second in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I was wondering if there was a way to refresh the progress bar every 1000 milliseconds because when I run my program I have to click the progress bar to get feedback from it.

```
private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        progressBar1.Value = (int)(power.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0}%", (power.BatteryLifePercent * 100));
    }
```

this is what I have so far.

Answer (score 2):

Executing a task every X time intervals is usually resolved using a Timer

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Moved here, supposing that you don't not needed to
    // set them to same value every second....
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 1000;
    t.Tick += timeElapsed;
    t.Start();
}

private void timeElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(power.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
    label1.Text = string.Format("{0}%", (power.BatteryLifePercent * 100));
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The progress bar didn't refresh every second.

Comment: This seems to be strange. You could place a breakpoint inside the timeElapsed event to check if it is called correctly. Then if the call is made look at the value in BatteryLifePercent moving the mouse over the property name.

Comment: Try to comment the line _Application.EnableVisualStyles();_

Comment: I managed to get it working but when I add my second progress bar it doesn't work. How can i add two progress bars?